# How can I Hash or Encrypt a field with EF CodeFirst?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Using EF Code First, how can I interrupt the saving of a field value so I can hash it?  A simple example would be a password field:

```
public class Account
{
    private string _password; 

    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _password;
        }
        set
        {
           _password = MyHashMethod(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This appears to work when saving the value to the database, but doesn't work when retrieving the value.

EDIT:
Changed _password = MyHashMethod(_password) to MyHashMethod(value) above.  Same correction needs to be made in the answer below.

Comment: I probably don't understand your question. When you save hashed password to database it will be stored hashed and you don't need to hash it again when you load it, don't you? Moreover hashing is one way operation (ok you can break the hash but it is different story) so when you load hashed password from DB you can't "decode" it to original value. If you want to do it you need encryption / decryption which in case of passwords is less secure.

Comment: You don't need to hash it again when you load it, but you do (in the case of the above password example at least) need to load the hash from the database in order to compare it.  So its not about unencrypting the saved value, but rather doing a one-way hash when writing, and reading the hashed value when reading.

Comment: This problem and solution are applicable to all Entity Framework users (not just those using Code First)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just make it like:

```
public class Account {
    public string HashedPassword { get; set; } 
    public string ClearTextPassword { 
        set { HashedPassword = MyHashMethod(value); }
    }
}
```

Only HashedPassword is stored in DB.